# Transparent navigation/menu bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, transparent

good day!

so im working on a certain parallax website, newbie here aneways. The problem is i want my navigation bar to be transparent just like this site : http://www.xplaye.com/en/
i tried using opacity and background :transparent but it does not work at all m.

anyone who has an idea? answers are greatly appreciated. thanks a lot CHEERS!

heres my css :

```
.nav{

    height: 40px;
    width:auto;

}

.nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right:20px;
    float: right;
    }
.nav ul li a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Calibri;
    }
.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #6be0d6;}
.nav ul li a:active{
    color: #6be0d6;
    }
```

Comment: It does work (opacity).... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PrQ36/)

Comment: Please add a demo showing us the problem

Comment: tnx @RUDDY for the idea. ya it worked! tricky css :) . but i want it to be more transparent(i want to see my background image clearly as if navigation items were floating) sorry my question above is not so complete apology for that. do you have any idea to achieve that? tnx a lot!

Comment: @gerah You just change `opacity: 0.5;` to what you need.

Comment: Your request here seems to be in contradict to the website you said 'just like' Nav bar on the link you provided has no background and opacity is not what you need here

Comment: @nathan742 ya right. i guess i really dont need opacity.wat i need is a clear background

Comment: If you need no color at all, just don't specify a background color. Just delete it from the css property.

Comment: tnx for that but  its no use. still it gives a white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone i don't know what exactly happen but when i applied this code it turns out OK :)

```
.nav{
    height: 40px;
    width:auto;
    height: 40px;
    width:auto;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by transparent? You can just delete background-color in css.

If you mean SEMI-TRANSPARENT, use rgba value:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7AJA/)

Comment: `delete background-color`... what?

Comment: If you say transparent it has no color at all. If you can still see some colors, then it's semi-transparent, and you can use rgba color value to achieve that.

Comment: If you use opacity then it makes the text color transparent as well. From what i see in the sample, only the background color is transparent.

Comment: Oh don't worry my brain just wasn't working. I read your answer wrong.

Comment: tnx guys. what i want is there's no color at all. i want to see the background image clearly.

Comment: ok so ive tried those codes and it didnt match to what i want to have.

Comment: If you want no color at all, just remove the background-color.

Comment: tnx for that but its no use. still it gives a white background

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
.nav{
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    width:auto;
}
```

to

```
.nav{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 40px;
    width:auto;
}
```

this will create a background color wich is black but has zero opacity

Comment: tnx for that :) but it only gives me a white background.what i need is a transparent navigation where i can see my background image. it was like menu items were floating :)